# How can I use FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) with P5.js in React?

Tags: reactjs, fft, p5.js, p5.sound.js

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk96O7N1Yo0&t=848s&ab_channel=ColorfulCoding), I tried to reproduce it in **React JS** to get an audio visualizer as in picture below.

[image: p5.JS Audio Visualizer]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-p5-p5-sound-forked-hgozjt?file=/src/index.js:1118-1213) is my try, for this project I used `react-p5` and `p5.sound`:

```
import Sketch from 'react-p5';
import 'p5/lib/addons/p5.sound';
```

Looking at the [official repo](https://github.com/Gherciu/react-p5) documentation, everything seems correct to me:

```
this.fft = new window.p5.FFT();
var wave = this.fft.waveform();
console.log('wave ', wave);
```

So why my variable `wave` returns in console an array of 1024 elements of the same value (`0.0039215686274509665`)?

Comment: Can I do something about it or in React the `waveform()` function is not supported?